# Google reCaptcha - Selected Image keep getting replaced with new Image

Tags: recaptcha

When we select a captcha image, it fading away and a fresh new image is getting replaced, as shown in below screenshot. Same for all images in that captcha. For over a year we had no problem, but only since 2 days we are seeing this(no change is done in the page).

Additionally, this problem occurs intermittently irrespective of browsers, OS, or Browser Incognito mode. 
We tried changing security level at Google Developer Console to low, medium and full but of no use. If you have any clue or handled this before, please let me  know.

Note: I see this problem for my work website, personal website, as well on [Quora Signup](https://www.quora.com/?unh=1ef8a4b746f6122be5f2bce4c18ac6ab&uid=6198324&time=1466418132119030#) page also!(may have to keep refreshing for a while to see the problem).

[image: Google captcha replaced always]

Comment: i am facing the same problem, even it is an expected behavior it is very hard to solve than normal captchas, i figured out that it became hard when i change the browser, in chrome it is very easy but when i used a chromium browser it becomes very hard !!

Comment: I've anecdotally seen that it's related to ad-blocking practices by the user also. Considering I was stuck filling the captcha for over 30 seconds, I consider this a disastrous choice by Google.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is expected behaviour, its just a different type of recaptcha challenge. You select all storefronts or whatever it tells you too and then it will fade out and load a new image. You have to repeat and click the matching images until there are no more storefront images left to select, then verify.

Comment: When I have to click more than 20 images, it becomes unacceptable, flow-inhibiting and constitutes bad UX. Give me back old Recaptcha at this point, it's less offensive and faster for me to be asked to validate their AI's efforts to transcribe books instead. I literally encountered this issue just now while logging into SO.

Answer (score 6):

This is completely confusing for users. If you do it once and it behaves a certain way and then the next time images fade out it seems like an error. This is not an answer but hopefully if enough people lodge an issue they can make a more sensible solution.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it was very annoying. At first i thought my captcha is bugged out.

The solution: Keep pressing the images they ask you to click on (for example "select all images with dogs")
As soon as there are no more pictures with "dogs" press the submit button and it should give you a positive response.

hope it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same issue. 
Its not a bug as many guys claim.

But first of all you have to **disable your ad blocker**, if you are using any.
When recaptcha i.e. asks for chosing a bus, select a bus until there is no bus anymore.
Then verify... this worked for me. i hope for you as well

Answer (score 0):

I went through many links and research for this behavior but as we all know grecaptcha is one type of service that protects your website from spam and abuse. Every time our CAPTCHAs are solved, that human effort helps digitize text, annotate images, and build machine learning datasets. This in turn helps preserve books, improve maps, and solve hard AI problems.

[Google Recaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html#advanced-security)

So this is basic thing which everybody knows who are using grecaptcha.

But your question is appreciable but this behavior is not related to security settings or OS or Browsers or anything else. 
(You will get rid of this behavior only when they change their behavior or launch new Captcha. :)